# controller inheritance: how to override controller's action and force using new action when Html.Action is called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, nopcommerce

I'm developing plugin for NopCommerce. I'd like to override an Action marked with [ChildActionOnly].

There is a  controller:

```
ShoppingCartController {

[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult FlyoutShoppingCart(){...}

}
```

I'd like to extend the original controller:

```
NewShoppingCartController : ShoppingCartController {

[ChildActionOnly]
public new ActionResult FlyoutShoppingCart(){...}

}
```

*a **new** keyword is used b/c in original impl the action is not virtual*

In RouteProvider i override routing like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Remove(RouteTable.Routes["ShoppingCart"]);

routes.MapLocalizedRoute("ShoppingCart",
                           "cart/",
                            new { controller = "NewShoppingCart", action = "Cart" },
                            new[] { "mynamespace" });
```

So this works fine for normal Actions but  doesn't work for the child only action b/c it is called using Html.Action where controller is specified:

@Html.Action("FlyoutShoppingCart","ShoppingCartController",...)

it means that original controller will be called here, thus i'll have to override Views to replace call like this:

```
@Html.Action("FlyoutShoppingCart","NewShoppingCartController",...)
```

or 
    @Html.Action("FlyoutShoppingCart",...)

Is there a way how to avoid changing views, and force to use NewShoppingCartController instead of ShoppingCartController?

Comment: i think you should try a route for a child action too. As a child action uses same routing like regular action. Just like you created a route for `Cart` action create another route for `FlyoutShoppingCart` too

Answer (score 4):

You'll kick yourself, but simply don't specify the controller.

```
@Html.Action("FlyoutShoppingCart")
```

Now, it will implicitly use whatever controller is in context, i.e. whichever the current main action belongs to.

Also, FWIW, using new to override is very clunky way to handle this. Instead, anything on a base class that can be overridden should be marked virtual.

```
public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
{

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public virtual ActionResult FlyoutShoppingCart() {...}

}
```

This in effect creates a self-documenting API for the class, so any one using it can tell at a glance where extension points are. Then, in your subclass, you `override` instead of `new`:

```
public override ActionResult FlyoutShoppingCart() {...}
```

Comment: i'm developing a plugin, the base implementation is as i described without virtual and Views also are standrad, I don't want to touch standard implementation or touch it in a minimal way

Comment: The second part I wrote is just advice; it doesn't apply to the solution of your specific issue here. However, unless you truly have no access to the base class, method hiding is not recommended. Using `new` merely hides the method or property on the base class; it doesn't override it. I haven't actually ever tried to use `new` in combo with a controller action, but in other instances, I seen conflicts caused by property hiding, especially whenever reflection is involved.